# How to transition from table view to a split view

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I cannot figure out how to create an application that starts off as a normal uitableview, and then when I click on a cell in that table view, it takes me to a uisplitview .. I really need to be able to do this. I know there is a template for UITableView and a separate one for UISplitView, but I need a way to combine the two, with the first view being the UITableView. Sorry if this is such a noob question, but I think if I can get this setup working, I can figure out the rest.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [presentModalViewController:animated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW29) if you touch a cell of your tableview and put in your splitViewController.

**A simplified code example for your tableViewController**

```
- (void)tableView:(*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(*)indexPath
{
    UISplitViewController *mySplitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];

    [self presentModalViewController:mySplitViewController animated:YES];

    [mySplitViewController release];
}
```

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://doronkatz.com/ipad-programming-tutorial-hello-world), it demonstrates how a splitviewcontroller is used.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I also need to create new project files though so I can implement the split view controller right? I guess I am not doing it right, but I created a UITableView project template, but I am not sure what type of files I need to add to the project to get the split view classes with the required methods.

Comment: Alright, first of all try to not use a splitviewcontroller and try the example with a simple UIViewController. If that is working advance to the UISplitViewcontroller. It's a bit more complicated, look at apple documentation: **"After creating and initializing an instance of this class, you must assign two view controllers to the viewControllers property. The split view controller has no significant interface of its own. Its job is to coordinate the presentation of its two child view controllers and to manage the transitions among different orientations."**